# WCF is sending Kerberos requests to domain controller when using Certificates and Transport SecurityMode

Tags: wcf, certificate, wcf-binding, kerberos, wcf-security

We have application with few modules, that connects to each other using WCF. We configured them to use NetTcpBinding (below is part of code responsible for setup). Both client and server part has similar settings, and everything works well.

Except that whenever client sends request to server there is additional query to our company domain controller for Kerberos TGT. It is AS-REQ type query with name-type NT-X500-PRINCIPAL and name is certificate subject (certificate used to encrypt connection). As response we get error ERR_C_PRINCIPAL_UNKNOWN.

It is not a problem for our application, but as we make quite lot of requests, we are flooding logs on domain controller. Is there any way to prevent system from sending above Kerberos requests?

Binding configuration:

```
var binding = new NetTcpBinding
{
    MaxBufferSize = 5000000,
    (...)
};


binding.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.Transport;
binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = TcpClientCredentialType.Certificate;
binding.Security.Transport.ProtectionLevel = ProtectionLevel.EncryptAndSign;
binding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = MessageCredentialType.Certificate;
(...)

channelFactory.Credentials.ClientCertificate.SetCertificate(
      StoreLocation.LocalMachine,
      StoreName.My,
      X509FindType.FindBySubjectDistinguishedName,
      certificateSubject);
channelFactory.Credentials.ServiceCertificate.Authentication.CertificateValidationMode = X509CertificateValidationMode.ChainTrust;
channelFactory.Credentials.ServiceCertificate.Authentication.TrustedStoreLocation = StoreLocation.LocalMachine;
channelFactory.Credentials.ServiceCertificate.Authentication.RevocationMode = X509RevocationMode.NoCheck;
```

Comment: hi, can you please add the app.config files? it is also good to know, if it is an anonymous client connection, or if both use certificates for authorization. does the client connect to the CD or the server or both?

Comment: To clarify client and server are both on one machine. And in .config file there are only timeouts (we overwrite them in code anyway). All security configuration is in code. Both of them are using certificates for authorization. I don't know who connects to CD, as both processes are on same machine.

Comment: ah ok. why do you use certificates for authorization, if both partners run on the same machine? Can you just ry a cross-machine communication, so you can see wich one connects to the DC?

Comment: I'm fully aware that cross-machine communication is better in our case. But right now we can't change that (legacy system).

Comment: I ment, just to try it cross machine, to see who is requesting the DC.So just build a simple testscenario (calculator or something)...

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that Kerberos queries were caused by this line:

```
binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = TcpClientCredentialType.Certificate;
```

If it was changed to None, then queries disappear (also this line was not required in our case).